# Change the Color of Text in ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The default color of `ListView` is red, I want to change it. I tried to use the `Label` inside the `ListView`, but it returns nothing (scree in empty, no values).

As u see the `Itemsource` in `ListView` and `Label` in `Text` is `Bind` to the same value, it is the reason for the empty screen.

How can I change the Color of Text?

```xml
<ListView
    BackgroundColor="#004B86"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label 
            Text="{Binding Attributes}"
            TextColor="White">
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Attributes**

```cs
foreach (var item in _credential.CredentialAttributesValues)
{
    _attributes.Add(item.Name.ToString());
    _attributes.Add(item.Value.ToString());
}
```

**Bindable Properties**

```cs
private ObservableCollection<string> _attributes = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Attributes
{
    get
    {
        return _attributes;
    }
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _attributes, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: you would need to change the color in `DetailedCell`

Comment: there isn't an option for.. can you give me an example?

Comment: I have no idea what `DetailedCell` is.  Is that a custom class in your code, or a class provided by some third party library?

Comment: @Jason my bad.. `DetailedCell` was defined in another page.. thanks for noticing it.

Comment: what text do you want to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am not sure if I fully understood what needs to happen, but if you want to change the color of something you can try to do the following. I did update some of the variable names to be something more appropriate. Let me know if this is correct or not

Your page where you load the ListView will look as follows, note the `x:Name` property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsPlayground.Controls;assembly=XamarinFormsPlayground" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsPlayground.Resources"
             x:Class="XamarinFormsPlayground.MainPage"
             x:Name="root">
    <ListView
    BackgroundColor="{Binding ListViewColor, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Colors, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding .}"
                        TextColor="White">
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ChangeColorCommand, Source={x:Reference root}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

In the code behind I set the BindingContext to be that of the ViewModel i've bound it to, the view model looks as follows:

```
public class BasicViewModel : BindableObject
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> colors = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        private Color listViewColor = Color.FromHex("#004B86");

    public Color ListViewColor {
        get {  return listViewColor; }
        set {
            listViewColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ListViewColor");
        }
    }
    public ICommand ChangeColorCommand => new Command<string>(x => ChangeColor(x));
    public ObservableCollection<string> Colors {
        get {
            return colors;
        }
        set {
            colors = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Colors");
        }
    }

    public BasicViewModel()
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        colors.Add("Red");
        colors.Add("Blue");
        colors.Add("Green");
        colors.Add("White");
        colors.Add("Orange");

        Colors = colors;
    }

    private void ChangeColor(string color)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(color))
        {
            var selectedColor = typeof(Color).GetRuntimeFields()
                .Where(x => x.IsPublic)
                .Where(x => x.IsStatic)
                .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(Color))
                .Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == color.ToLower())
                .First();
        
            ListViewColor = (Color) selectedColor.GetValue(null);

        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

In the XAML we bound our color names to be `{Binding .}` because the items inside of the `DataTemplate` use the `ItemSource` as its BindingContext, and since it is just a collection of strings, it only has itself to bind to, that's what the `.` binding means.

Then, we bind the TapGestureRecognizer on the Label to the BindingContext of the overall page, hence the interesting syntax for the command binding.

The magic part of the code lies in the  ChangeColor method, it will go through the runtimefields of the Color struct and find the color that matches the name we tapped on. The .ToLower() portion of the code is there just to negate any case sensitivity in the color names.

Using the above methodology you should be able to extend it to fit your needs as well. If you want to change the color of the Text that the ListView is actually rendering then you will just need to modify the above XAML's binding a little bit. Really all you would need to do is define a regular color for your overall listview (say like black) then for where you have the `Color="White"` on your `Label` just set its binding to be `{Binding BindingContext.ChangeColorCommand, Source={x:Reference root}, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Answer (score 0):

In your `DetailedCell`, there must be some labels where you can set the `Title` and `Subtitle`. So you can change the `TextColor` property of those labels there to change the text color.

Update:

```xml
<ListView BackgroundColor="#004B86" ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            
            <ViewCell>
                
                <Label 
                    Text="{Binding Attributes}" TextColor="White">
                </Label>
                
            </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: yes, @Jason told me yesterday.. thanks for your response

Comment: hey, now I have another ```<ListView BackgroundColor="#004B86" ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" HasUnevenRows="true"> </ListView>```.. How could I change the text color?

Comment: It's the same. Where do you set the text? Change the corresponding label's textColor. Share me the code of your ViewCell and I can give you more help.

Comment: I added the code above... actually this `ListView` is Bind with `Attributes` in `ViewModel`, and it's a `foreach` loop .. if u add the label and use the bind, it didn't show the values then.. have a look and u will get it.

Comment: Have a try to use Attributes.Add(item.Name.ToString()); instead of _attributes.

Comment: @IngmarBergman See my updated answer, contents should warp inside a ViewCell.

Comment: Text={Binding .} the bindings inside of your ItemTemplate use the itemsource as its binding context. Since your item source is just a collection of strings, just bind the whole thing. Then as far as changing the color goes, you will have to look at some examples that xamarin has. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/XamlSamples/XamlSamples/XamlSamples/NamedColor.cs

Comment: @SomeStudent thanks for ur response, but your answer is very hard to implement.. the @Jack's answer is more easy to implement.. but I'm just not getting the value on screen, when I implement his answer, and the problem is with `Binding`.

Comment: @IngmarBergman have you tried changing the binding of your text to be {Binding .} instead of {Binding Attributes}? The text field of a label expects a string value, not a collection of strings, which is what attributes is. Also as I mentioned, When it is inside the data template, it uses the ItemSource as its binding conext, and the Attributes collection<string> does not have a property named Attributes. What portion of my answer is more complex to implement out of curiosity?

Comment: I changed the Binding of `ItemTemplate` to {Binding .} and it worked... thanks.. can u please paste this in ur Answer (below), so, I could Mark it as Accepted Answer.

Comment: Please refrain from having extended discussions in comments - this is not what comments are for. Feel free to start a [chat].